# groovy eval string to list which contains strings

Tags: string, list, groovy, eval

I have a list object which contains strings. I'm converting this list to a string.
Then i want to evaluate the the list-string back to a list object, containing the strings.

```
Eval.me(["abc"].toString())
```

How get this working? Eval should give me ["abc"] (= list object containing a string).

Thanks

Comment: Why not serialise it to json and back? More secure and parsable by more things

Comment: It's because of the software i'm working with: [QFTest (great JAVA-GUI-Testtool)](http://www.qfs.de/en/qftest/index.html). In it i can embed isolated groovy skripts. The QFTest-Procedure-Mechanism can only handle a single string as return value. It is special.

Comment: Json is a single string

Comment: I'm not familiar with Json. Can you give me a short example solution for my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would get more flexibility using [`inspect()`](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#inspect(java.lang.Object))

```
def list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
def string = list.inspect()

assert string == "['a', 'b', 'c']"
assert string instanceof java.lang.String

// Get back original list from String
def originalList = Eval.me( string )
assert originalList == list
assert originalList instanceof java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: `inspect()` - nice tip!

Comment: Thanks. Thats what i'm looking for. With these i can handle also mixed lists like [1, 'a']

Comment: Glad that was helpful, but I would look at what Tim is suggesting about using Json. That will be a more viable approach although this answer is addressing the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
["abc"].toString()
```

returns string as below:

```
[abc]
```

So you can see it isn't valid list definition. Evaluating `["test"]` string will return ArrayList:

```
assert Eval.me('["test"]').class == ArrayList
```

Comment: Your answer gave me the hint. I have now following solution 

`def a = ["abc"]
def b = "'" + a + "'"
Eval.me(b)`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at dmahapatro's answer with great tip to use `inspect()`!